# Environment for questions/exercises with solution at the end + hyperlink from questions to solutions and vice versa

Tags: exercises, hyperlink

I would like to write an overleaf document with exercises (divided by sections and maybe even subsections) and, at a section at the end, their solutions. Like for example, as it is done in a book.

I would like my code to have the following structure (this is not mandatory, but I would like it to be well structured, and this seems one good option):

```
\section{About you}
\begin{ex}
How tall are you?
\begin{sol}
I am 6'5.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
How are you?
\begin{sol}
I am fine thanks.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\clearpage
\section{Computations}

\begin{ex}
1+1?
\begin{sol}
That's easy, it is 2.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
How about 6+3?
\begin{sol}
Hmm, 9.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
17x3?
\begin{sol}
51.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Last one, 64+46?
\begin{sol}
110.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\clearpage
\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions
```

And it should produce something like:

**1. About you**

1.1 How tall are you?
1.2 How are you?

**2. Computations**

2.1 1+1?
2.2 How about 6+3?
2.3 17x3?
2.3 Last one, 64+46?

**3. Solutions**

1. About you

1.1 I am 6'5
1.2 I am fine thanks

2. Computations

2.1 That's easy, it is 2.
2.2 Hmm, 9.
2.3 51.
2.4 110.

Finally, I would like to put an **hyperlink in every question to its solution and one in the solution to the question** (for example, if I click question 1.1, I go to solution 1.1 and vice-versa), if possible without labelling every question and every solution.

Comment: To use hyperlinks try to label every solution or what You want and find some more here: https://zims-en.kiwix.campusafrica.gos.orange.com/wikibooks_en_all_maxi/A/LaTeX/Hyperlinks

Comment: I'm not interested in a solution which involves labelling every question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{answers}

\newif\ifsolutions
\solutionstrue % hide or show solution

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{%
    \hyperlink{ex:\theex}{Exercise}\hypertarget{sol:\theex}{}}[chapter]
\Newassociation{sol}{Soln}{ans}
\renewenvironment{Soln}[1]{\par\bigskip\noindent{\bfseries \hypertarget{ex:#1}{}\hyperlink{sol:#1}{ #1}}\quad}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\usepackage[linkcolor=blue,colorlinks=true,unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Try}
    \Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
    \section{About you}
\begin{ex}
How tall are you?
\begin{sol}
I am 6'5.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
How are you?
\begin{sol}
I am fine thanks.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\clearpage
\section{Computations}

\begin{ex}
1+1?
\begin{sol}
That's easy, it is 2.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
How about 6+3?
\begin{sol}
Hmm, 9.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
17x3?
\begin{sol}
51.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Last one, 64+46?
\begin{sol}
110.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
    
    \Closesolutionfile{ans}
    \ifsolutions
    \section{Solutions}
    \input{ans1}
    \fi
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't compile?

https://www.overleaf.com/1422544716vdnrkjbdbxsm

Comment: I have tried it. Please remove this line `\theoremstyle{definition}`. Then, It runs.

Comment: Thank you. Moreover, I don't know if you can correct this, but the hyperlink takes me one line below from where it should